# Catching data from a graph in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

There is some data like HR value , calorie and Skin temperature in my project and  the same is also displayed on the top of  a graph view . But how can I save  the values of the above three parameters so that the user can view his previous details by  click of  a history button anytime . Data for the three parameters should be fetched automatically . Please help .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write data to external or internal storage of the phone, so that these can be read e.g. in the OnClick Method of your button after the application was ended, you can use http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html.

So 1. you set the permissions to write / read from external/internal storage:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

2.
Saving any raw data types like a String with outputStream:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "This text becomes written on internal storage";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try{
   outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
   outputStream.close();
}  catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();   
}
```

3.Analog Read the String in with Calling openFileInput() and passing it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream. Read bytes from the file with read(). Then close the stream with close().

You can also write and read entire ArrayList. So you should first when your activity starts read the last ArrayLists from internal storage in OnResume(), and always when your activity pauses with OnPause() write the ArrayLists to your internal storage. 
You can add or delete Data that should be saved/deleted to/from the ArrayList easily.

Comment: So u mean  I can write : "Hr" : + "calorie" : + and so on and  passs it on to String tring variable ?

Comment: I would create a class for representing OneMeasurement that has an private integer HR; private integer calorie, andsoon.. for each value. also write public setter/getter variables for the class OneMeasurement. Then in your Code you have a OneMeasurement variable in which u have setted each value. If you want to save them int storage at any point, you use that outputStream but use outputStream.write(yourOneMeasurementVariable.getBytes());